# Vertically centering <div>s with multiple lines

Tags: css, html, center

I know it's been asked a few times, but upon playing around a bit I still couldn't center what I need to. What I'm looking to do it center those buttons vertically on the page. I want to put centered text above it, too.

My (sloppy) code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Novicode/R2GZF/22/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id= "mail" class="cbtn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.cbtn {
    display:inline-block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:transparent;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    margin: 2px;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
}

.cbtn:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#F3734F;
}

#mail {
    background-image:url(http://data.novicode.com/data/img/mail.png);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it, assuming you want the buttons centered both horizontally and vertically on the page.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="button-wrap"> 
        <a href="#" id="mail" class="cbtn"></a>
        <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
        <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
        <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
        <a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.button-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You need to declare the width and height properties of the body and html elements to be 100%, and the same for `div.wrap`.

The trick is to wrap the links/buttons in `div.button-wrap`, which is absolutely positioned **and** given specific width and height values to match the buttons.  The height of 60px is based on the height of the `.cbtn`, and the width of 350px is 5 times (60px + 2x2px + 2x1px + 4x1em) which is about 350px.  However, since we can use `text-align: center` for centering the inline blocks, the exact width is not too critical, just make it wide enough.

The centering works by setting all the position values to 0 (left/right/top/bottom) and then setting `margin: auto`.

This is all based on CSS 2.1 so it should work in most browsers.  The only limitation is the inline-block property, which IE7 does not recognize.

However, since you are using CSS2 animations, inline-block is probably okay.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/METYC/

Full page view: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/METYC/show

Answer (score 0):

You could set the following rules on the div:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: -(height of div);
  margin-left: -(width of div);
}
```

Example link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/AT8S6/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm obviously very new to this, but I'd assume the current size of the div is 64px (height), by 312 px (width), because of the 5 buttons (each 60x60px), and a 2px margin. Filling in those sizes did NOT center it, though. http://jsfiddle.net/Novicode/R2GZF/25/embedded/result/

Comment: I modified the code and ran into yet another problem. I want the text above the buttons to be size 96px, however this brings up an issue in horizontal centering. It does not position correctly because (I think) the left margin forbids it to be farther left than the buttons themselves. I started playing around but couldn't find an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

http://jsfiddle.net/AT8S6/

you can change the width,height and margin property of section for different results .

**HTML**

```
<div>
<section>
<a href="#" id= "mail" class="cbtn"></a>
<a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
<a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
<a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
<a href="#" class="cbtn"></a>
</section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    div {
    text-align: center;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    border:2px #000 solid;
}

a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

div section {
     width:65%;
    height:50%;
    margin:20% auto;
}


.cbtn {
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:transparent;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    margin: 2px;
  -o-transition:.5s;
  -ms-transition:.5s;
  -moz-transition:.5s;
  -webkit-transition:.5s;
  transition:.5s;
    float:left;
}

.cbtn:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#F3734F;
}

#mail {
        background-image:url(http://data.novicode.com/data/img/mail.png);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```